# SQL Fill in Gaps with last value untill new value occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a dataset with gaps in the status column. Similar questions on here have the missing dates, but with mine the dates are given. In this example I need the latest status to fill in the NULL gaps below until a new status occurs then that new status needs to fill in the gaps.

> ex:
>   create table #tableA
>
> (
>   Campaign Varchar (100)
>   ,Date_of_data Date
>   ,Status varchar (100)
>   )
>
> insert into #tableA
>   values
>   ('banner1','11/2/2015','DELIVERING'),
>   ('banner1','11/3/2015','DELIVERING'),
>   ('banner1','11/4/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/5/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/6/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/7/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/8/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/9/2015','PAUSED'),
>   ('banner1','11/10/2015','PAUSED'),
>   ('banner1','11/11/2015','PAUSED'),
>   ('banner1','11/12/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/13/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/14/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/15/2015',null),
>   ('banner1','11/16/2015','DELIVERING'),
>   ('banner1','11/17/2015','DELIVERING'),
>   ('banner1','11/18/2015','DELIVERING')
>
> select * from #tableA

the status 'DELIVERING' on 11/3 needs to fill in for 11/4-11/8 and then the status of 'PAUSED' on 11/11 needs to fill in for 11/12-11/15 so the final data set would effectively look as such

> Campaign|Date_of_data|Status
>   banner1    2015-11-02  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-03  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-04  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-05  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-06  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-07  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-08  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-09  PAUSED
>   banner1    2015-11-10  PAUSED
>   banner1    2015-11-11  PAUSED
>   banner1    2015-11-12  PAUSED
>   banner1    2015-11-13  PAUSED
>   banner1    2015-11-14  PAUSED
>   banner1    2015-11-15  PAUSED
>   banner1    2015-11-16  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-17  DELIVERING
>   banner1    2015-11-18  DELIVERING

Thanks!

Second scenario....

The below solutions work, but I have run into a new scenario. The below works great for "banner1" but when you get to "banner2" the records for 11/12-11/15 don't get filled with 'READY'. They fill with 'PAUSED' and Im not sure why. Is it an ordering issue?

Desired logic: fill NULL records with the first "previous" status

> drop table  #tableA
>   create   table #tableA
>   (
>     Campaign Varchar (100),
>      Date_of_data Date,
>      Status varchar (100)
>   )
>
> insert into #tableA
>   values
>      ('banner1','11/2/2015','DELIVERING'),
>      ('banner1','11/3/2015','DELIVERING'),
>      ('banner1','11/4/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/5/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/6/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/7/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/8/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/9/2015','PAUSED'),
>      ('banner1','11/10/2015','PAUSED'),
>      ('banner1','11/11/2015','PAUSED'),
>      ('banner1','11/12/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/13/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/14/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/15/2015',null),
>      ('banner1','11/16/2015','DELIVERING'),
>      ('banner1','11/17/2015','DELIVERING'),
>      ('banner1','11/18/2015','DELIVERING'),
>     ('banner2','11/2/2015','DELIVERING'),
>      ('banner2','11/3/2015','DELIVERING'),
>      ('banner2','11/4/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/5/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/6/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/7/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/8/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/9/2015','READY'),
>      ('banner2','11/10/2015','READY'),
>      ('banner2','11/11/2015','READY'),
>      ('banner2','11/12/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/13/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/14/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/15/2015',null),
>      ('banner2','11/16/2015','DELIVERING'),
>      ('banner2','11/17/2015','DELIVERING'),
>      ('banner2','11/18/2015','DELIVERING')
>
> SELECT Campaign, Date_of_data, 
>         COALESCE(Status, prevStatus) AS Status  
>   FROM #TableA AS t1
>   OUTER APPLY (
>     SELECT TOP 1 Status
>     FROM #TableA AS t2
>     WHERE t1.Date_of_data > t2.Date_of_data AND Status IS NOT NULL
>     ORDER BY Date_of_data DESC) AS t3(prevStatus)
>   ORDER BY 1,2

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SSMS 2014 @GiorgosBetsos

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server, then you can get required result with `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT Campaign, Date_of_data, 
       COALESCE(Status, prevStatus) AS Status      
FROM #TableA AS t1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 Status
   FROM #TableA AS t2
   WHERE t1.Date_of_data > t2.Date_of_data AND Status IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY Date_of_data DESC) AS t3(prevStatus)
ORDER BY Date_of_data
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ac3b/1)

Comment: Thanks for this. It works great however im not sure it does what I was looking for logically. Would you mind looking at the updates I made to my question? Thank You

Comment: Never mind @GiorgosBetsos I think I figured out the missing piece. and t1.campaign = t2.campaign

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using 2 windowed functions.

The query you select from uses a windowed SUM function.  The IIF() function will return 1 when a value is present, but otherwise will be zero.  The windowed sum will show the running total as Date_of_data increases.  This will essentially create a grouping for a value and it's following nulls.

The query you use to return data, will then use that grouping and show the first value present, which by definition, will be the last non-null value.

```
SELECT
  Campaign,
  Date_of_data,
  Status,
  FIRST_VALUE(Status) OVER (
    PARTITION BY Grp
    ORDER BY Date_of_data ASC 
  )
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      Campaign,
      Date_of_data,
      Status,
      SUM(IIF(Status IS NULL, 0,1)) OVER (ORDER BY Date_of_data ASC) AS 'Grp'
    FROM 
      #tableA
  ) A
```